# Create an animation when changing the path of a subLayer to another path

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I have a `UIView` and its layer in which I added a CAShapeLayer as a subLayer with a path.

When I tap on a `UIButton`, I change the path of the subLayer with another path.

How can I animate this?

Is it possible to have an animation as soon as the path changes?

I tried to add:

```
let caAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
caAnimation.keyPath = "path"
caAnimation.duration = 2

shapeLayer.addAnimation(caAnimation, forKey: "path")
```

in the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method of my `UIView` in order to have an animation when the path is changed in `layoutSubviews()` method but it doesn't work.

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

I added a `fromValue` and `toValue` as parameters for the animation. I am wondering if I have to do that all the time or if there is a way to animate without specifying a `to` and `from` value and that it takes automatically the value before the change and the one after and make the animation.

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Comment: Nop, not that I remember anyway. I did something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's in objective-c, but I think you'll get the gist of it.

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
anim.duration = 2.0;

UIBezierPath *path = myPath;
anim.fromValue = (__bridge id)layer.path;
anim.toValue = (__bridge id)path.CGPath;
layer.path = path.CGPath;
[layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"path"];
```

If I'm not mistaken, you can also leave the toValue or fromValue as nil, and it'll set it to the current value.

It's important to pay attention to setting the actual path of the layer, so it doesn't revert back to the original when completing the animation.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work without setting `fromValue` and `toValue`